# Pascal no compiler message

Tags: ide, mint, pascal

In every Ubuntu Distro i tried i had a problem with Free Pascal IDE.

The problem was that after some time compiler error message window would disappear and i no longer could see errors i made, i would have to search them manually.
I tried reinstalling FPC but i had no luck and only solution was to reinstall the OS

I tried searching on a lot forums for a solution and haven't found anything

How can i fix it? How can i get compiler error message window to work again?

**UPDATE**

I fixed the problem by deleting these files in the home directory:

- fp.cfg
- fp.dsk
- fp.ini
- fp___.err
- fp___.out